# Android Service Defined in 2 Apps

Tags: android, android-service

I have a few android apps and I want to have them all use the same service. I don't want to just define the service in one manifest and have them all depend on that app; can I just define the same service with the same process name in every manifest, that way no matter which app gets installed first, the service gets started?

Comment: I think if you make it a bound service and then check and see if it's already started that should work (but never tried it) bit of a maintenance problem though :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a similar question asked on the google [forum](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/a595a40214fabb25#) a SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337529/installing-apk-from-within-application-in-android) that might relate.  So I suppose you could

A. Embed the service in each application, if running use it, else start it, though versioning might be a problem

B. Get the user to install and apk with the service from the market place if not already present on device

I have probably not thought through all the issues, but it seems like B might be a better option from a version and maintenance perspective